# coding a responsive website

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design

Hi guys I hope there are someone that can give a solution for this:

When coding a responsive website I get the problem when the screen turns on a ipad it don't reset the zoom meaning that when users turn to vertical it will zoom in and you have to reload the page or zoom out to see the full design is there a way to force a reset on the zoom or reload when users turn the screen. I pref if the solution comes in css becuase it's only on ipad device the problem is and I can control this in the .ccs fil assignt to devices

I know there has been some questions about this but nothing of that I could use becuase I'm not trying to block that users can zoom in or out but I'm trying to reset the zoom on screen turn

Best regards

Lasse

Comment: Try adding this meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">`.

Comment: If the above doesn't work, read more about other HTML meta tags for mobile devices, as I am 99% sure that is where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following meta tag in your `HTML` code (Inside `head` tag)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: thx for the answer yes I saw this one before but this code cut some of the left side of the design holding the ipad in landscape position and furthermore it block the user from using zoom themselves witch is not a good thing you have a solution the get around that

Comment: What I found out myself when trying to understand the code above is that it will put the website in the standard resolution of the webpage so where my problem is, is that my website is actually fitted in to the screen so apparently I just have to make a @media exactly to ipad's screen resolution and not between last say (min-width : 768px) (max-width : 1100px)